# What are the rules used by a reasoner

Tags: owl, reasoning

In OWL.

I know that if

```
ObjectProperty AB
```

and

```
AB domain A
```

and

```
AB range B
```

and

```
A subClassOf AB something
```

then the reasoner can infer that

```
A subClassOf B
```

1- What is the notion behind this inference?

2- Is there any references that explains the whole set of rules for how does the reasoner works, i.e. what are the rules that a reasoner applies to turn implicit knowledge into explicit one? like this one presented in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning behind these inferences follows the rules outlined here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-direct-semantics/#Object_Property_Expression_Axioms